# elif statement in Kotlin does not execute

Tags: java, kotlin, if-statement

I'm just starting with Kotlin.
This code doesn't give off errors. But I don't get the output I need. The `else if` statement seems to get no effect, even if I don't enter any character in the field. What did I do wrong?

```
fun main(){
    print("Enter First Name: ")
    var firstname: String? = readLine()
    print("Enter Last Name: ")
    var lastname: String? = readLine()
    print("Prefix (Ms/Mr/Mrs)?: ")
    var prefix: String? = readLine()

    if (prefix!!.contains(".")){
        prefix = prefix.substring(0,prefix.length-1)
    }

    if (firstname!!.isNotEmpty() && lastname!!.isNotEmpty() && prefix.length != 0) {
        println(Applicant(firstname,lastname,prefix).message)

    }
    else
        if (firstname == "\n"){
            println("The First Name field is empty. Re-run the program to try again.")
    }
        if (lastname == "\n"){
            println("The Last Name field is empty. Re-run the program to try again.")}


}
```

Comment: If you don't enter anything as input, then `firstName == ""`, not `"\n"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readLine` output doesn't contain the `'\n'`, it only returns the characters read till the `'\n'` is encountered. So you will have to update your `else if` check to `firstname == ""` or in a more clear way `firstname.isBlank()`

Answer (score 0):

So I did the else-statement this way, and it works. But I don't know why the `lastname` needs to have `!!` but the others do not?

```
else {
        if (firstname.isBlank()){
            println("The First Name field is empty. Re-run the program to try again.")
        }
        if (lastname!!.isBlank()){
            println("The Last Name field is empty. Re-run the program to try again.")
        }
        if (prefix.isBlank()){
            println("The prefix field is empty. Re-run the program to try again.")
        }


    }
```

Comment: If you've already non-null-asserted `!!` the other values earlier in the code, they don't need it again since they can't have possibly become null in the intermediate.